# OpenCV passing values by reference or pointer to callback functions

Tags: c++, opencv, callback, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to avoid using global variables in an openCV project (I'll have my supervisor no doubt teach me as to why they are bad rah rah rah :) -  but at the moment they seem to be the only way I can get information out of mouse and trackbar callback functions.

Using the mouse example - at the moment I have as globals:

```
vector<Point2d> vectorOfPoints;
int clickCount = 0;
```

At the moment I have this line in main:

```
setMouseCallback("test",onMouse, NULL);
```

Then above main:

```
void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int f, void* ){           
    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){  
        vectorOfPoints.push_back(Point(x,y));
        clickCount++;
    }
}
```

It is working, but what is the syntax to get read/write access to both vectorOfPoints and clickCount inside the callback function without using globals?

I have found this question online a few times but the answers are unclear to me or wont work. There are hints within comments as how to do it, but I am so far unable to interpret the jargon correctly.

I was hoping for something as simple as the syntax I use to pass variables as references to methods ...

```
void referenceExampleMethod(vector<Point2d>& referenceExample){
    //do something with referenceExample...
}
```

...less convoluted the better

I'm scared to ask (jargon overload!) but maybe it's 100% relevant - what is void*  ??

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the first part of the @jschultz410's answer about the pointer to some place in memory. However, I disagree with using raw pointers in the wild.

You should define your own data type, holding all your data, it could be `struct` or `class`, or `std::pair`, or `std::tuple`, whatever, the choice is yours.

Then you create an object of that type and use its address in the last argument for `setMouseCallback`.

The main thing you must ensure - the life time of that object must cover the life time of the window. That is, the object must be created before the first call to `onMouse` and destroyed after the last one. You could do this by declaring the variable in the beginning of your `main`. Then the object will be created early after the program start and destroyed near its finish automatically by the compiler. Here is the example.

```
typedef std::pair<vector<Point2d>, int> data_holder_type; // note the absence of references, this pair holds std::vector and int

void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int f, void* ptr){
    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){  
        data_holder_type *dholder = static_cast<data_holder_type *>(ptr);

        dholder->first.push_back(Point(x,y));
        dholder->second.clickCount++;
    }
}
....

int main(void)  {
    data_holder_type dholder;

    // add code to initialize your dholder;

    ...
    setMouseCallback("test", onMouse, &dholder);
    ...

    cv::waitKey(); // wait until the window is closed

    // read values from dholder and process them

} //dhloder is deleted somewhere here
```

Another important thing is the concurrent access to this object. `onMouse` is called from the separate [parallel thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29), and if your `dholder` is read or modified both in `main`, and `onMouse` simultaneously while the window is open, [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) will occur. In general, they usually cause unpredictable and very hard to catch bugs.

Everything is fine while your `main` doesn't access `dholder` until the window is closed.

As for your question about `void *`. Note the lines inside `if` in `onMouse`. `ptr` points to the object of type `void`. That object has no any members, `first`, or `second`, or any others. You'll get the compiler error if you'll try to access them using `ptr` (e.g. `ptr->first`). Therefore you have to cast this pointer to pointer to another type, that contains some info about the object it points to, `data_holder_type *` in this case.

Any pointer type can be cast to `void *`, and `void *` can be cast to any other pointer type. This allows you to have several different callbacks for different windows.

Beware of wrong casts! No checks is done by compiler.

This example shows how to set 3 different mouse callbacks for windows with different titles.

```
typedef blah-blah-blah1 data_holder_type1; 
typedef blah-blah-blah2 data_holder_type2; 
typedef blah-blah-blah3 data_holder_type3; 

void onMouse1(int event, int x, int y, int f, void* ptr){
    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){  
        data_holder_type1 *dholder = static_cast<data_holder_type1 *>(ptr);

        dholder->first.push_back(Point(x,y));
        dholder->second.clickCount++;
    }
}

void onMouse2(int event, int x, int y, int f, void* ptr){
    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){  
        data_holder_type2 *dholder = static_cast<data_holder_type2 *>(ptr);

        // processing, related to another data type
    }
}

void onMouse3(int event, int x, int y, int f, void* ptr){
    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){  
        data_holder_type3 *dholder = static_cast<data_holder_type3 *>(ptr);

        // process
    }
}

int main(void)  {
    data_holder_type1 dholder1;
    data_holder_type2 dholder2;
    data_holder_type3 dholder3;

    // add code to initialize your dholders;
    ...
    setMouseCallback("test1", onMouse1, &dholder1);
    setMouseCallback("test2", onMouse2, &dholder2);
    setMouseCallback("test3", onMouse3, &dholder3);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Very nice - it's working !  but with a change:   dholder->second.clickCount++;    needs to be:  dholder->second++;   And also I had to look up how to access pair variables, turns out it's done thusly:  get<0>(data_holder_type), which I've #defined as my original variables :)

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter to `setMouseCallback` is passed back to you when `onMouse` is called.  That is what the `void *` is in `onMouse`: the pointer that you passed to `setMouseCallback`.  A `void *` is a pointer to an unspecified type.  You can think of it as a generic pointer to some place in memory.

In your case, you would likely pass the address of a struct that either contains or points to the variables that you want to have access to inside `onMouse`.

```
#include <utility>

...

typedef std::pair<std::vector<Point2d>&, int&> my_pair;

...
my_pair *p = new my_pair(vectorOfPoints, clickCount);  // TODO: needs to be deallocated eventually
setMouseCallback("test", onMouse, p);
```

The above assumes that `vectorOfPoints` and `clickCount` are already allocated somewhere else (e.g. - dynamically, statically, on the main thread's stack, etc.) and will remain so for the duration of your callbacks.  Then,

```
void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int f, void *pptr)
{
    my_pair *p = (my_pair*) pptr;

    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){  
        p->first.push_back(Point(x,y));
        p->second++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Memory leak is here. my_pair is created with new, but never deleted.